# GWT - show/hide <tr> in a HTMLPanel

Tags: gwt, html-table

I have a HTMLPanel with a `<table>` inside.
I want to show/hide a `<tr>` from the the java code.

I tried to put the `<tr>` inside other HTMLPanel and to hide the Panel. Something like this:

```
...
<tr>
  ...
</tr>
<g:HTMLPanel ui:field="name">
    <tr>
    ...
    </tr>
</g:HTMLPanel>
<tr>
  ...
</tr>
```

code:

```
name.setVisible(false);
```

and it works, but it causes a strange behaviour in the presentation.

How could I do this???

Thx a lot!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an `@UiField TreeRowElement rowName` with the HTML being `...<tr ui:field="rowName">...</tr>...`. Then use the TreeRowElement to show/hide that row.

Comment: Hi, I guess you mean TableRowElement, in this case, how I show/hide the element? it doesn't have the setVisible method... thx a lot

Comment: Try `rowName.getStyle().setDisplay(Display.NONE);`

Comment: Hi Tassos, you are right!, I can swear I looked for the getStyle method.... anyway thx a lot!!!!

Answer (score 5):

Expanding upon @Tassos answer:

Java

```
@UiField TableRowElement expanded;

boolean exp=false;

    expandme.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent clickevent) {
            if(exp){
                expanded.getStyle().setDisplay(Display.NONE);
            } else {
                expanded.getStyle().clearDisplay(); //took a little while to find.
            }
            exp = !exp;
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<tr ui:field="expanded">
```

Where expandme is any element that you can attach a click handler to, (ex Anchor,Button,etc)

Comment: clearDisplay() was useful, otherwise the table row didn't remember its initial width after a hide/show (just setting it to BLOCK or INLINE again didn't work). Thanks!